# Use dapper to retrieve multiple result sets

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, dapper

I have a structure like this :

```
class Classroom {

    public int Classname { get; set; }
    public List<Student>  { get; set; }
}

class Student {

    public string Studentname { get; set; }
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public List<Subject>  { get; set; }
}

class Subject {

    public string Subjectname { get; set; }
    public int Marks { get; set; }
}
```

I have to write a stored procedure using dapper that returns Object of Classroom as the final result. Since I don't know any way to do that using dapper so I am currently
iterating over list of Student class and using a SP to fetch the marks list for that particular student. But I want a single database call to fetch the entire result set. So I am thinking of 
making a new class of the following format :

```
class IntermediateClass
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string Subjectname { get; set; }
    public int Marks { get; set; }
}
```

and storing the result in list of IntermediateClass. But this will result in repetition of the StudentId and I will then have to map this list to my original object in a separate logic.
I can't seem to decide the best way to solve this problem.

Is there any way I can do this by writing a single stored procedure and no separate logic and if not what is the best way to fetch the result?

Comment: It's a (1-->*) relationship. What's the problem?

Comment: The problem is that for a particular index in List<Student>, there will be another List<Subject> for which the Studentname and Studentid will be common and I have to return the List<Student> with all the respective lists having their proper values and I don't know any way of doing this with a single stored procedure.